# Python Tkinter: How to GET font info

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

I would like to get information on the actual font (especially the size) being used in the Tk menu.
I was able to find that the `font` property of the menu is set to `TkMenuFont`.
However, if I try to inspect its content, it seems I cannot get anything beyond some string representations:

```py
print(dir(menu['font']))
```

outpus:

```py
 ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', 
   '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', 
   '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', 
   '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', 
   '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 
   'string', 'typename']
```

So, the question is: **how to get information on the Tk fonts?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`tkinter.font.Font`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/font.py#L25) class appears to be capable of turning `menu['font']` into something with inspectable attributes:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.font import Font

root = tkinter.Tk()
menu = tkinter.Menu()
font = tkinter.font.Font(font=menu["font"])
print(font.actual())
```

Result:

```
{'family': 'Segoe UI', 'size': 9, 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'underline': 0, 'overstrike': 0}
```

You can access individual properties with the usual dict indexing syntax, for example:

```
font.actual()["size"]
```